# Hodge dual of $4$-form in Minkowski spacetime

Tags: differential-forms

In the Wikipedia article about the [Hodge dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual), I'm clear on how to compute the Hodge star of $1$-forms, $2$-forms, and $3$-forms in the $4$-dimensional Minkowski spacetime of metric signature $(+---)$. What I'm not so clear on is if there is a way to compute the Hodge star of the $4$-form $dt \wedge dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$. I know that by definition the Hodge star sends $k$-forms to $(n-k)$-forms, where $n$ is the dimension of the underlying vector space. So in that regard $4$-forms would be sent to $0$-forms under the Hodge star. My question is would that be a smooth (scalar) function $\phi(t, x, y, z)$?

Comment: In fact, $dt \wedge dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$ *is* (up to a choice of sign) the volume form of the Minkowski metric, so $\ast(dt \wedge dx \wedge dy \wedge dz) = \pm 1$.

Comment: Thank you. Can it be computed explicitly?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? It was computed explicitly in my first comment.

Comment: You only computed it up to a sign. But to determine the sign we need to know the orientation. The notation suggests an orientation which gives the answer as +1

Comment: Travis: So your conclusion follows directly from the fact that the $4$-form in my question is the volume form of said metric? I think I'm clear now.

Comment: ziggurism: So it should be $-1$ if the signature is $(-+++)$, right?

Comment: The orientation is an additional datum that was not specified---it's not usually taken to be part of the data of the metric. This is the 'choice' in "up to a choice of sign". Fixing the order $(t, x, y, z)$ for the variables determines an orientation ov $V$, namely the one for which $dt \wedge dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$ is positively oriented.

Comment: It follows from the definition of $\ast$. If we regard $1$ as a $0$-form, we have $\ast 1 = 1 \wedge \ast 1 = \langle 1, 1 \rangle \Omega = \Omega$, where $\Omega$ is the volume form of the metric (which depends on the orientation). On the other hand, on $k$-forms we have $\ast^2 \alpha = s (-1)^{k (n - k)} \alpha$, so in our case ($k = 0$, and Lorenztian signature gives $s = -1$) $\ast \Omega = \ast^2 1 = -1$. Thus, $\pm$ is $-$ if the given $4$-form is positively oriented (in which case it is $\Omega$) and $+$ if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regard the scalar $1$ as a $0$-form: By the [definition of the Hodge star operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual#Formal_definition_of_the_Hodge_star_of_k-vectors) $\ast$, we have
$$
\ast 1 = 1 \wedge \ast 1 = \langle 1, 1 \rangle \Omega = \Omega ,$$ where $\Omega$ is the volume form of the metric (which depends on a choice orientation).

On the other hand, on $k$-forms $\alpha$ the square of the Hodge star operator satisfies the [duality identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual#Duality)
$$
\ast^2 \alpha = s (-1)^{k (n - k)} \alpha ,
$$
where $s \in \{ \pm 1 \}$ depends on the signature of the metric. In our case, Lorentzian signature in dimension $4$, $s = -1$. Thus,
$$\ast \Omega = \ast^2 1 = -1 .$$

Now, $(dt, dx, dy, dz)$ is a (pseudo-)orthonormal coframe, $\Omega = \pm dt \wedge dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$---the choice of sign is the same as the choice of the orientation. Thus,
$$\ast (dt \wedge dx \wedge dy \wedge dz) = \ast(\pm \Omega) = \mp 1 ,$$
where $\mp$ is $-$ if $dt \wedge dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$ is positive and $+$ if not.

Answer (score 0):

$\star(\mathrm{d}t\wedge \mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y\wedge \mathrm{d}z)=-1$

According to the definition of the Hodge star operator, $\omega\wedge \star\mu=\langle \omega, \mu \rangle \mathrm{d}t\wedge \mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y\wedge \mathrm{d}z$, while

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\langle \mathrm{d}t\wedge \mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y\wedge \mathrm{d}z, \mathrm{d}t\wedge \mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y\wedge \mathrm{d}z \rangle
={}& 
\mathrm{det}
\begin{pmatrix}
\langle \mathrm{d}t, \mathrm{d}t \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d}t, \mathrm{d}x \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d}t, \mathrm{d}y \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d}t, \mathrm{d}z \rangle\\
\langle \mathrm{d}x, \mathrm{d}t \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d}x, \mathrm{d}x \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d}x, \mathrm{d}y \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d}x, \mathrm{d}z \rangle\\
\langle \mathrm{d}y, \mathrm{d}t \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d}y, \mathrm{d}x \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d}y, \mathrm{d}y \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d}y, \mathrm{d}z \rangle\\
\langle \mathrm{d}z, \mathrm{d}t \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d}z, \mathrm{d}x \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d}z, \mathrm{d}y \rangle & \langle \mathrm{d}z, \mathrm{d}z \rangle
\end{pmatrix}
\\={}&-1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
no matter which signature of the metric you use (check it).

Then the answer is a natural deduction.

Note that the value $s$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#Duality does not change with your choice of the signature difference of the metric.